# hiding portion of div jquery sortable widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some markup similar to below, and I am trying to hide the "some_row" TR's.

```
<div id="sortable">
<table>
    <tr><td>Some Title 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="some_row"><td><textarea ...></td><tr>
</table>    
<table>
    <tr><td>Some Title 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="some_row"><td><textarea ...></td><tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable")
    .sortable({
        helper: function (e, o) {
            o.find("#some_row").hide();
            return o;
        },
        start: function () {
            $(".some_row").hide();
        },
        stop: function () {
            $(".some_row").show();
        }
    })
    .disableSelection();
});
```

Initially i started with just `start` and `stop` events, then I added `helper` because the, what i am guessing is a cloned selected row, had a hidden some_row div but the same height.

Anyways, the above works as far as style perfectly, however it appears the widget is still taking into account the original heights of the surrounding divs.

Is there anything I can do to salvage this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the hide on **`.somerow`** before the helper is returned.

The helper is a clone of the original div and what you see being dragged.  So when you hide the rows the clone has already been created.

The refresh that runs after start is done to reload the sortable objects to adjust for the new height.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6naRs/8/)

```
$(function () {
$("#sortable")
.sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    cursorAt: { left: 0, top: 10 },
    helper: function (e, o) {
        $(".some_row").hide();
        o.find("#some_row").hide();
        return o;
    },
    start: function () {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );
    },
    stop: function () {
        $(".some_row").show();
    }
})
.disableSelection();
});
```

Also you can define the cursor position when dragging (relative to the helper) and the cursor type that displays when hovering using the `cursor` and `cursorAt` options of the [jqueryui sortable api](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Comment: Mike, this is great it is almost there. However, if you notice in fiddle when you select a row the divs collapse but the cursor remains below the div like it thinks its a bigger div than it is.

Comment: @TomFobear I updated the Fiddle for you and added the options to my code.  You can specify the cursor in relation to the helper with cursorAt and define the cover cursor with cursor.

Comment: Acctually, I found this still does not fix the height issue. when the height of the toggled row is increased it becomes noticable: http://jsfiddle.net/6naRs/6/

Comment: @TomFobear I added a refresh after the start.  That should resolve the issue.  In this case the sortable api remembered the heights of the other divs we hid, not the clone we were dragging.